# JFileChooser has no FIle Name text field option

Tags: java, swing, java-8, jfilechooser

I have the following Java 8 Swing code:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Browse");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose file as input");
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel Filter", "xls", "xlsx");
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);

        if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mainWindow) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            File selection = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            createFile(selection);

        }

    }
});
```

The idea is that the user selects a directory and then types the name of a **new** file that the app will then create. But when I click the button this is what I see:

[image]

Notice how there's no "**File Name**" text field where you can enter the new file name? What configurations do I need to change in order to get this?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to allow to select a non-existing file with a "File Open" dialog. Try `showSaveDialog` instead.

Comment: Ahh thanks @tkausl (+1) I didn't realize there even was a `showSaveDialog` method. If you turn your comment into an answer that explains that different `showOpenDialog` and `showSaveDialog` open a `JFileChooser` in different "modes", I'll happily give you the green check!

Comment: And wanting them to select a directory but then configuring the chooser to only accept files and then adding a filename filter that enforces only .xls/.xslx files makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the [`showOpenDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog(java.awt.Component)) which, as the name suggests, shows a "Open File" dialog to select a file to open. It usually doesn't make sense to allow a non-existent file to be opened.

If you want to allow the user to select a new file, you probably want the [`showSaveDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showSaveDialog(java.awt.Component)) which shows a "Save File" dialog and (should) allow a new file to be created.

Comment: Sorry for disturbance, but it's not working in my case. When I upload file first time it's empty but when i select JChooser again it came with last selected file name. In such case if file has deleted then it comes in in-consistant stage.